# Has not been selected VS was not selected

Tags: tense, present-perfect

What is the difference of saying "has not been selected for the prize" and "you were not selected for the prize"? I understand that the first one means that there is a possibility to be selected in the future. The second one, however, it means that it is done; you have zero chance to get the prize. Is this correct?